# Print a 3D shape

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, 3d

Write a program or a function to print the following cube (if you allow me to call it so) in different sizes:

```
          ^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L
         //^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L
        ////^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L
       //////^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L
      ////////^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L
     //////////^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L
    ////////////^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L
   //////////////^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L
  ////////////////^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L
 //////////////////^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L
////////////////////^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L^L
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ " " " " " " " " " " "
 \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ " " " " " " " " " " "
  \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ " " " " " " " " " " "
   \\\\\\\\\\\\\\ " " " " " " " " " " "
    \\\\\\\\\\\\ " " " " " " " " " " "
     \\\\\\\\\\ " " " " " " " " " " "
      \\\\\\\\ " " " " " " " " " " "
       \\\\\\ " " " " " " " " " " "
        \\\\ " " " " " " " " " " "
         \\ " " " " " " " " " " "
           " " " " " " " " " " "
```

The shape is made of pairs of characters: `^L`, `"`, `\\`, `//`

#### Input:

An integer greater than 1, representing the size of the shape.
<sub>The one showed above has a size of 11 because each side of each face is made of 11 pairs of characters.

Note that only two faces are fully displayed.</sub>

#### Output:

A cube of the given size.

Here's another example, with a size of 5:

```
    ^L^L^L^L^L
   //^L^L^L^L^L
  ////^L^L^L^L^L
 //////^L^L^L^L^L
////////^L^L^L^L^L
\\\\\\\\ " " " " "
 \\\\\\ " " " " "
  \\\\ " " " " "
   \\ " " " " "
     " " " " "
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest in bytes wins.

<sub>Even though you are not required to do so, it would be nice if you could provide an easy way to check the output of your code</sub>

Comment: May we choose which characters to use, as long as all 8 are unique?

Comment: @shaggy I think it's better to stick with the original characters. It's true that the algorithm would be quite the same even using other characters, but you may lose the "3D illusion". So then it wouldn't be an algorithm to print a 3D shape anymore

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 81 bytes

```python
k=n=input()
while 1:k-=1;i=k^k/n;print' '*i+(n+~i)*2*'\/'[k/n-1]+'^ L"'[k<0::2]*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9s2zzYzr6C0REOTqzwjMydVwdAqW9fW0DrTNjsuWz/PuqAoM69EXUFdK1NbI0@7LlNTy0hLPUZfPRooqWsYq60ep@CjBOTZGFhZGcVq5f3/b2gIAA)

Reuses some ideas from my answer on [Draw an ASCII hexagon of side length n](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217375/20260), including using the index `k/n-1` both to select between `/` and `\` in an order where the `\` doesn't need escaping, as well as to terminate the loop with error at the end.

Answer (score 6):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <sup><s>27</s></sup> 22 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
｛╷２×/×^L⁸×＋］：↕vL∙ "╋∔ｒ
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjVCJXUyNTc3JXVGRjEyJUQ3LyVENyU1RUwldTIwNzglRDcldUZGMEIldUZGM0QldUZGMUEldTIxOTV2TCV1MjIxOSUyMCUyMiV1MjU0QiV1MjIxNCV1RkY1Mg__,i=NQ__,v=8)

### Explanation

```
{|2×/×^L⁸×+]:↕vL∙ "╋∔r
{          ]           map each i from 1 to n:
 |2×                   decrement and double i
    /×                 repeat "/" that many times
      ^L⁸×             repeat "^L" n times
          +            add that to get one line
            :          copy the top half
             ↕         mirror vertically (mirrors characters)
              vL∙" ╋   replace 'vL' with '" '
                    ∔  and add vertically
                     r center the whole art
```

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 121 bytes

```javascript
s=>(j=n=>' '[b="repeat"]((a=n>=s)?n-s:s+~n)+(a?"//":"\\\\")[b](a?s*2-n:n+1)+(a?"^L":' "')[b](s)+'\n'+(~n?j(--n):''))(s*2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtBCoMwEEWvUrLJjCHaugxEL9CeQC0kGlrFTsSRLr16KvWvHu/xJ/d13K/jsmmKQ0jeJrYVTJZsJS@y8VasYQluEx2As1RZxpo0G1Y7oQJXi6IQRrTHBDa@OwxnpSZD6nb2510YeRHyXxmVbEkq2KmeQGtCIyUiHB9MfSSOc8jn@AIPD7e98z6M80mroyF@ALPyiojpBw)

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 78 bytes

```ruby
->n{puts (0...n).map{|i|puts ' '*(j=n+~i)+?/*i*2+'^L'*n;' '*i+?\\*j*2+' "'*n}}
```

Builds an array for the bottom half while printing the top half, then dumps the bottom half at the end. I also tried recursion but it was longer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vuqC0pFhBw0BPTy9PUy83saC6JrMGLKauoK6lkWWbp12Xqaltr6@VqWWkrR7no66VZw2SytS2j4nRygIJKigBBWtr/6dFm8b@BwA)

Comment: you can remove the space between `puts` and `' '`

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>28</s> 26 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)!

Without [this bug](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/issues/181), `»∊¶¡` could be just `∊`.

```
L<·'/×»∊¶¡„^L„ "‚I×Iδи˜ø.c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATgAx/9vc2FiaWX//0w8wrcnL8OXwrviiIrCtsKh4oCeXkzigJ4gIuKAmknDl0nOtNC4y5zDuC5j//8xMQ)

**Commented**:

```
L<·'/×»∊¶¡      # generate the left part
L               # push the range [1..n]
 <              # decrement to get [0..n-1]
  ·             # double each value: [0, 2, ..., 2*(n-1)]
   '/           # push the string '/'
     ×          # for each number in the list, repeat the string this many times
      »∊¶¡      # vertically mirror to get lower left half

„^L„ "‚I×Iδи˜   # generate the right part
„^L             # push the string '^L'
   „ "          # push the string ' "'
      ‚         # pair into a list: ['^L', ' "']
       I×       # repeat each string input times 
         Iδи    # for each string create a list containing the string input times
            ˜   # flatten into a single list

 ø              # zip both parts to get the rows
   .c           # join each row, centralize and join by newlines
```

[Try it with step-by-step output!](https://tio.run/##bVJNSsNAGN17io9uqhJTq7uiBxB6g2Jhkn5tRiYzYeZLS7vqUryAIiJ4B38K7tqlIJ6hF4mTZIJTaTYhmffe9977RhkWcSyKPthnu3zIcpMAJQiayQnCoBuG8rpXngSXm7fg4MLhRhhrTFESkIIJEgxOLfKk62PXHw1Y5ZFAQBYnMGUix56FB3AWQBiG9n18aJlHPrXd@WfHkOZyAu1O20Nt7t2AsdK1uszTCDVwWZEENxSAxgwZ@SqUcAMpk3MgnqLxLX9ub@/W7@uX8tcUNfGYCTGHlGttZ7isQs3sEIFjgoSJscffLp@H/f3Oh/32LhBa@4HQ2gU@NqthvExmPbAqmS2xFA0qhl/eVdWL/XTJq2acOpdZTnVs8Cnfrz@r3Sodwa6ZEbqRECtJjMu6RNwj6ml@PTXbEYwIZePdWIpAF@FvlyuHXvAMIkUJZEyTaSqvrqSa@fphXBNulF13ZdkCAojtpdRM8IU1LUdQnUZzkDgTXPoGi@L8Fw)

Some slightly longer alternatives:

```
L<·'/×»∊¶¡εNI@i„ "ë„^L}I×«}.c
L<·'/×»∊¶¡ε„^LNI@i„ "}I×yì}.c
L<·Â«εNI@i'\×„ "ë'/×„^L}I×«}.c
```

Comment: `‚øJ.c` can be `ø.c` for -2, because the `ø` uses two arguments implicitly with a string-list in the new 05AB1E version (unlike the legacy, where it would transpose a string-list as if it were a character-matrix), and the `.c` joins implicitly.

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://git.sr.ht/%7Engn/k), 69 bytes

```
{` 0:,/',/$(`" "`"//"`"^L";`" "`"\\\\"`" \"")@'&''(t;|t:+(|!x;!x;x))}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxLs6pOUDCw0tFX19FX0UhQUlBKUNLXBxJxPkrWEG4MEAAphRglJU0HdTV1dY0S65oSK22NGsUKayCq0NSs5eJKUzA0BAC+2xJX)

Not a great fit for the language, but an interesting exercise...

- `(t;|t:+(|!x;!x;x))` build a nested list containing the number of copies of each type of symbol to take. (i.e. spaces from x..0,0..x, slashes from 0..x,x..0, and x copies of `^L` and  `"`).
- `&''` convert to indices, e.g. `3 1 5` => `0 0 0 1 2 2 2 2 2`
- `` (`" "`"//"`"^L";`" "`"\\\\"`" \"") `` build another nested list (of the same shape), this time containing symbol versions of the output characters. This avoids having to enlist the individual strings and simplifies the list notation a bit. Since they contain special characters (as opposed to being alphanumeric), the contents need to be enclosed in `"`'s, with `"` and `\` also needing to be escaped.
- `(...)@'(...)` retrieve the correct number of copies of each type of symbol
- `,/',/$` stringify the symbols, and raze them into the lines of the output
- `` ` 0: `` print them (this elides the wrapping `"`s and `\` escapes otherwise present)

Answer (score 4):

## Java 11, <s>148</s> 136 bytes

```java
n->{String r="",t=r;for(int i=n;i-->0;t+=" ")r=t+"//".repeat(i)+"^L".repeat(n)+"\n"+r+t+"\\\\".repeat(i)+" \"".repeat(n)+"\n";return r;}
```

-12 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hZDBasMwEETv@YpFJwnVTtPSk1C@oMklx7oFVVGCUmdt1utACf52d5OaQgslexDMzluY0SGcQnHYfoyxDl0Hq5DxPAPIyIl2ISZYXyTAhinjHqIWB9A4WQ4zeToOnCOsAcGPWCzPE0heqTv25HYNXW@yR5eLYnnv2HoFypBnq@ZzVVJqU2CdjVVvzz8SRVaoLFnBKplfIFTqL@kocU8I5IbRXaK1/Xst0aaEpyZv4Sj19HfCl1cIZur22XE6lk3PZSsW16ixjPrJXGv@6z/e8BeLG8CDmf5xGL8A)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{                        // Method with integer parameter and String return-type
  String r="",              //  Result-String, starting empty
         t=r;               //  Temp-string, starting empty as well
  for(int i=n;i-->0         //  Loop `i` in the range [input, 0):
      ;                     //    After every iteration:
       t+=" ")              //     Append a space to `t`
    r=...+r+...;            //   Change the result-String to:
                            //    Prepend to the result-String:
      t                     //     The spaces `t`
      +"//".repeat(i)       //     plus '//' repeated `i-1` amount of times
      +"^L".repeat(n)       //     plus '^L' repeated the input amount of times
      +"\n"                 //     plus a newline
                            //    Append to the result-String:
      t                     //     The spaces `t` again
      +"\\\\".repeat(i)     //     plus '\\' repeated `i-1` amount of times
      +" \"".repeat(n)      //     plus ' "' repeated the input amount of times
      +"\n";                //     plus a newline again
  return r;}                //  After the loop, return the result-String
```

Comment: [136 bytes](https://tio.run/##hZDBasMwEETv@YpFJwnVTtPSk1C@oMklx7oFVVGCUmdt1utACf52d5OaQgslexDMzluY0SGcQnHYfoyxDl0Hq5DxPAPIyIl2ISZYXyTAhinjHqIWB9A4WQ4zeToOnCOsAcGPWCzPE0heqTv25HYNXW@yR5eLYnnv2HoFypBnq@ZzVVJqU2CdjVVvzz8SRVaoLFnBKplfIFTqL@kocU8I5IbRXaK1/Xst0aaEpyZv4Sj19HfCl1cIZur22XE6lk3PZSsW16ixjPrJXGv@6z/e8BeLG8CDmf5xGL8A), mostly changing `t=" ".repeat(...)` with `t+=" "` and rearranging the rest a bit.

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 88 bytes

```powershell
param($n)$n..1|%{($l=' '*--$_)+'//'*($j=$n-$_-1)+'^L'*$n
$b=,($l+'\\'*$j+' "'*$n)+$b}
$b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVPUyVPT8@wRrVaQyXHVl1BXUtXVyVeU1tdX19dS0Mly1YlD8jXNQSKxPmoa6nkcakk2eoA1Wqrx8QA@Vna6gpKIHFNbZWkWqDk////TQE)

---

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>104</s> <s>102</s> 92 bytes, Alternative

```powershell
param($n),{$l='//';'^L';$i++}*$n+,{$l='\\';--$i;' "'}*$n|%{.$_}|%{' '*($n-$i-1)+$l*$i+$_*$n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVPU6daJcdWXV9f3Vo9zkfdWiVTW7tWSyVPGyIeE6NuraurkmmtrqCkDhKvUa3WU4mvBVLqCupaQAOAkrqGmtoqOVpArSrxQCW1////NwUA)

The script generates the array of scriptblocks and executes its in the same context. Less golfed:

```powershell
param($n)filter g{' '*($n-$i-1)+$l*$i+$_*$n}
,{$l='//';'^L'|g;$i++}*$n+,{$l='\\';--$i;' "'|g}*$n|%{.$_}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>42</s> 32 bytes

```
ＮθＧ⌈⊖θ\↓‖Ｃ‖Ｍ↑Ｆθ«Ｐ×^Lθ↘»Ｆθ«Ｐ×" θ↙
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYyxDoIwFEVn@IqmU0lwdMFRFhMxhuhGTBAf0KT0lWfBEOPu4Ff6I7VxYTGO995zbtWWVGGpnNtoM9jd0J2BRB@twj2qqUEtkvfrGbMUKoIOtIWLX2PGi4J7KMMRRJLiTfuQQ62gsms0k5hjJomQRHI0vquRmPfZPQyyQVlpSGorDrKDq@CnLY9ZH3ksmH9z2bTWV4//bsHZD3kL9dd1bukWo/oA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the size.

```
Ｇ⌈⊖θ\↓
```

Print a small triangle of `\`s.

```
‖Ｃ‖Ｍ↑
```

Reflect it twice, once horizontally to complete the bottom left block of `\`s, once vertically with mirroring to produce the top left block of `/`s.

```
Ｆθ«Ｐ×^Lθ↘»
```

Print the top right block of `^`s and `L`s.

```
Ｆθ«Ｐ×" θ↙
```

Print the bottom right block of `"`s and spaces.

Comment: Doesn't the vertical reflection change the slashes in backslashes? If so, wow!

Comment: @Davide It depends on whether you use `‖Ｃ` or `‖Ｍ`, see my updated answer.

Comment: Oh that's powerful

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) [commit 2a96748](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/commit/2a9674862ecaf9b7b1b66178782d47e8445df325), <sup><s>123</s> <s>121</s></sup> 119 bytes

```sh
alias R=repeat
R "i=a=$1" {s=${(l:--i:)};R b++ s+=//;R a s+=^L;<<<$s}
R a {s=${(l:i++:)};R a-i s+='\\';R a s+=' "';<<<$s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/MSczsVghyLYotSA1sYQrSEEp0zbRVsVQSaG62FalWiPHSlc300qz1jpIIUlbW6FY21ZfH8hOBLHifKxtbGxUimu5QAIw9Zna2hD1ibqZIFXqMTHqMB3qCkrqUD3///83BQA)

This specific version fixes a bug that would otherwise require `i=a=$1` to be in quotes. TIO doesn't have that version obviously, so the linked one is two bytes longer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <sup><s>97 93</s></sup> 92 bytes

```python
lambda a:sum(zip(*((' '*(x:=a+~i)+'//'*i+'^L'*a,' '*i+r'\\'*x+' "'*a)for i in range(a))),())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FclBCsIwEIXhqwxuZiYpdCGCFHoDjxCEEY0OpGmIKVQXXj0mi7f4v5c@5bXG4znl6mdXgyy3u4BM722hryYyRAhoaJ9msT9li@OIRi1eL2hk6J/ajM6h2S3CoSH7NYOCRsgSnw8SZh6IuXYP3T1pLG1pK815Srl34Hr6Aw)

Output is a [tuple of lines](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17095).

*-4 by @Seb*

*-1 by @Danis*

Comment: You can save a byte by changing `'\\\\'` to `r'\\'`, and 3 more by [using Python 3.8 for its walrus operator](https://tio.run/##FclBCsIwEIXhqwQ3M5O0FBFBAr2BRwjCiEYH0jTEFKqXj8niLf7vpW95r/F0Sbn62dXAy/3Biu1nW/AnCTUiKNC425lHGY9kYJpAi2ENtysMotttMjgHeu@oDkB@zUqURJU5vp7IRDQgUe0eunuUWNrSVpqTTbl3oHr@Aw "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: `a-i-1` --> `a+~1` save 1 byte

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>160</s> <s>135</s></sup> 130 bytes

Saved 5 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

```c
p(n,c){for(;n--;)printf(L"\n//\\\\L^ \"  "+c+n%2);}i;t;f(n){for(t=i=1;i;i+=t,t=i>n?i=n,-1:t)p(n-i,9),p(!p(2*n,6-t),p(2*~-i,2-t));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU7RCsIwDHzfV8SB0K4tYwMVjdUf8BOGMAqTgsaxFXwY89OtKRPvJdzlcjlnbs7F2AvSTk7dcxBIxqDsB0@hE5e8obJsGJcrNDlArpyidS1x9hiwE7QcBetthR69skEzOdHZW9KmOgTJ2cbrvdS9WPWiLkhvTUisLt68qJlwXOR/8Gg9CZlNGTA4F0RSCSxskMfRwg5BKZKwWBKSY2RH6oJ/9def6@c/dc7mLH5cd29vYzSvLw)

#### Explanation (before some golfs)

```c
d;p(n,c){                             // p is a helper function that prints     
                                      // n/2 pairs of chars  
  for(d=0;n--;d^=1)                   // loop n times, flipping d between  
                                      //   0 and 1 each time  
    printf(L"                         // print one char of a pair of 
                                      //   chars based on c (then select the  
                                      //   other one on the next loop as d 
                                      //   flips between 0 and 1):  
             //                       //   c==0: '//'  
               \\\\                   //   c==2: '\\'  
                   ^L                 //   c==4: '^L'  
                      \"              //   c==6: '" '  
                                      //   c==7: any number of spaces
                          \n"         //   c==9: p(1,9) prints a newline  
             +c+d);                   // use c and d to select char
}                                     // returns 0 
i;t;f(n){                             // f is the main function    
  for(t=i=1;                          // main loop i goes from 1 to n and  
                                      // back down to 1 again  
    i;                                // loop until i is 0  
    i+=t,                             // bump i up for 1st half and then  
                                      // bump i down for 2nd half  
         t=i>n?i=n,-1:t)              // flip t from 1 to -1 half way thru  
               p(n-i,7),              // print leading spaces   
               p(2*~-i,1-t),          // print left side slashes   
               p(2*n,5-t),            // print right side of cube   
               p(1,9);                // print newline
}                                     //
```

Comment: This is shorter than the one I made before to post the challenge. Nice usage of `printf`! I need to learn that

Comment: How does it work this `L` in printf, before the string? I tried to find out, but I get only results about the L in `%L`

Comment: @Davide It's notation for a [`wchar_t`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character#Programming_specifics) string literal,

Comment: Thank you so much for this information!

Comment: @Davide So the way it works is the 8-bit `char`s are zero expanded when converted to 32-bit `wchar`s.   `printf` sees the zeros as end of strings so only prints the single `char`.that's pointed to by the pointer after the `int` offset is added.

Comment: Woah, that's a nice trick! It's like a putchar, but instead of passing a character you pass an index to a string (that doesn't need to belong to a variable name). I think it is valuable enough to be posted among [those tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/tips-for-golfing-in-c) even though demonstrating it's value isn't trivial

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 30 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ḶṚżḤƊØ.xⱮ;€3,5ẋ$;ṚḤ$$ị“/\^"L ”
```

A monadic Link accepting a positive integer which yields a list of lists of characters (a list of lines).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUUAuv9qZWxsef//4bi24bmaxbzhuKTGisOYLnjisa474oKsMyw14bqLJDvhuZrhuKQkJOG7i@KAnC9cXiJMIOKAnf/Dh1n//zQ)** (The footer calls the Link and joins the resulting lines with newline characters.)

#### How?

```
ḶṚżḤƊØ.xⱮ;€3,5ẋ$;ṚḤ$$ị“/\^"L ” - Link: integer, n    e.g. 3
Ḷ                              - lowered range            [0,1,2]
    Ɗ                          - last three links as a monad - f(that):
 Ṛ                             -   reverse                [2,1,0]
   Ḥ                           -   double                 [0,2,4]
  ż                            -   zip together           [[2,0],[1,2],[0,4]]
        Ɱ                      - map with:
     Ø.                        -   bits                   [0,1]
       x                       -   repeat elements        [[0,0],[0,1,1],[1,1,1,1]]
               $               - last two links as a monad - f(n):
           3,5                 -   three pair five        [3,5]
              ẋ                -   repeat (n times)       [3,5,3,5,3,5]
         ;€                    - concatenate each = x     [[0,0,3,5,3,5,3,5],[0,1,1,3,5,3,5,3,5],[1,1,1,1,3,5,3,5,3,5]]
                    $          - last two links as a monad - f(x):
                   $           -   last two links as a monad - f(x):
                 Ṛ             -     reverse              [[1,1,1,1,3,5,3,5,3,5],[0,1,1,3,5,3,5,3,5],[0,0,3,5,3,5,3,5]]
                  Ḥ            -     double               [[2,2,2,2,6,10,6,10,6,10],[0,2,2,6,10,6,10,6,10],[0,0,6,10,6,10,6,10]]
                ;              -   concatenate            [[0,0,3,5,3,5,3,5],[0,1,1,3,5,3,5,3,5],[1,1,1,1,3,5,3,5,3,5],[2,2,2,2,6,10,6,10,6,10],[0,2,2,6,10,6,10,6,10],[0,0,6,10,6,10,6,10]]
                      “/\^"L ” - list of characters = '/\^"L '
                     ị         - index into (1-indexed & modular, i.e. 10->")
                                                     -> ['  ^L^L^L',
                                                         ' //^L^L^L',
                                                         '////^L^L^L',
                                                         '\\\\ " " "',
                                                         ' \\ " " "',
                                                         '   " " "',
                                                        ]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 27 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ü╚lTà╨ú%Ñ►F↔33j♦ü♂D▄P;L.⌂î↑
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=81c86c5485d0a325a510461d33336a04810b44dc503b4c2e7f8c18&i=5%0A10&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>134</s> 116 bytes

```php
for($f=str_repeat;$i<$n=$argn;)$s=($t=$f(" ",$i++).$f("//",$n-$i).$f("^L",$n)."
").$s.strtr($t,'/^L','\\ "');echo$s;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcyxCsMgFIXhvU8R5IJKjE6djHTrlEcICaFo46IXvc9fa8hy4DvDjye2@YV9Qy4CgqtU9uLRH2QhzpAcHOWbrITqBJCDINjAFMRxlPqCMV1pgnhzWy5KzR6sH1X3HPUuKW62hSu@rgPj0vrPmaHa1p6/jBRzqm16/wE)

Yes, much shorter to build the string..

**EDIT:** a huge 18 bytes saved thanks to optimization from Dom Hastings

**Old version kept just for the fun:**

## 157 bytes

```php
for($f=str_repeat;$i<2*$n=$argn;$s.='//')$i++<$n?printf("%".($n-2+$i)."s%s",$s,$f("^L",$n)."
"):printf("%".(5*$n-$i)."s",$f('\\',4*$n-2*$i).$f(' "',$n)."
");
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3LCsIwEEX3foUMU5KYPqDYjU3pzpWfUJQuGs1mEpJ8v3GKIG6G4cy5d8IrFDMHntZHiXZKOT7iFrY1j@hMf0KacI1PGjG1k@g6odBpbZDmEB1lK6GCViI1vUanWkhVghpTjXy533glhgdQl3994Nrmq8NuimUR9XmH/JDxjo4gfuGxlOHtQ3aeUmmuHw)

Here is an infamous PHP answer based on `printf`. Couldn't think of an uglier looking piece of code for now, but I'll work on it (starting to think it would be better to build the whole string)!

Comment: Nice! Good dedication to check the alternative as well! You can also save a few more bytes using `strtr` too: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcyxCsMgFIXhvU8R5IJKjE6djHTrlEcICaFo46IXvc9fa8hy4DvDjye2@YV9Qy4CgqtU9uLRH2QhzpAcHOWbrITqBJCDINjAFMRxlPqCMV1pgnhzWy5KzR6sH1X3HPUuKW62hSu@rgPj0vrPmaHa1p6/jBRzqm16/wE "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: @DomHastings huge optimization! if you want to post it as your own answer be sure I'll upvote it, or else I'll edit. Yes for these kind of simple problems I like to try to think by myself first rather than just port other answers

Comment: Not at all, I was looking at a version but even using `strtr` I was at 133, so it's mostly your work! Please edit in! :) Yeah, I try to avoid looking at other approaches too, at least until I think I'm done!

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 172 bytes

```
(m=MapThread[Join,{DiamondMatrix[#][[1;;#+1,1;;#]],2BoxMatrix[#][[1;;#+1,1;;#+1]]}];Print/@StringJoin@@@(Join[m,4Reverse[m]]/.{0->" ",1->"//",2->"^L",4->"\\\\",8->" \""}))&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcxBC4IwHAXwrxILQnE1NQ@BGCM6RUJYt/kPRk7dYTPWCEH87Lbde5ff4T2e4rYXilv54ktbLIEqSv5@9Ebwhl0GqfF0llwNuim5NXJka2AsyfN1lGAPAE5Pw/i/jBKAGfKbkdoSencT3flPSmngZQpnlfgK8xFMAZDdFG@PaIVw4iAE4dT5vCKcOWsXhA9@UCM0h@FmaQmtuO4E28ew/AA)

**Brief explanation**:

Construct the upper part `m` with [DiamondMatrix](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiamondMatrix.html) and [BoxMatrix](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoxMatrix.html):

```
m = MapThread[Join, {DiamondMatrix[n][[1 ;; n + 1, 1 ;; n]], 2BoxMatrix[n][[1 ;; n + 1, 1 ;; n + 1]]}]
```

Derive the whole matrix `M` from `m`:

```
M = Join[m, 4*Reverse@m]
```

you can visualize it with:

```
MatrixPlot[M, Frame -> None]
```

when n = 10, it's like this:

[image: when n = 10]

Replace each number from the matrix with corresponding string:

```
M/.{0->" ",1->"//",2->"^L",4->"\\\\",8->" \""}
```

Convert each row to string and print it:

```
Print/@StringJoin@@@%
```

Answer (score 3):

## batch <s>317</s> <s>309</s> <s>301</s> <s>291</s> <s>284 bytes</s> 276 bytes

```bat
Cls&@Set $=@Set 
%$%/Ah=%1*2,z=0
%$%F=@For /L %%a in (1 1 &%$%P=@^<nul set/p&%$%C= @If ,%%y LEQ %1 
%f:a=y%!h!)Do @(%$%/Aw=%1-z
%F%!w!)Do %P%=ESCC
%F%!z!)Do%C%(%P%=//)Else %P%=\\
%F%%1)Do%C%(%P%=^^L)Else %P%^"=ESCC""
%C:EQ=SS%(%$%/A z+=1)Else%C:,=not %%$%/Az-=1
Echo()
```

**Cube.bat**

Notes:

- *must be run from the command line using:* `Echo(cube.bat n|Cmd /V:on`
  *where `n` is an integer representing cube size and cube.bat is the filename of the file*
- lines `1` and`3` end wth trailing spaces
- **requires windows 10 with virtual terminal support**
- `ESC` is a stand in for the ANSI escape character, [As it can't be pasted here, the scripts raw paste data can be found here](https://pastebin.com/AaNxX84B).

  - Or it can be generated by opening the command prompt and typing:

    - `>"%TEMP%\escape.chr" Echo(`<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>027</kbd> then pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
  - Or output using a for loop with `Echo off`:

    - `(For /F "skip=4 DELIMS=" %a in ('Echo(prompt $E^|cmd')Do Echo(%a) >"%TEMP%\escape.chr"`

Vt sequence `ESCC` *('cursor right')* is used to get around `<nul set /p`'s inability to output leading spaces.

example output:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 37 bytes

```
Ḷ,Ṛ$ạ’;,ʋ³ẋ@"ɗ€"“ “//“^L”,“ “\\“ "”ẎY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjm06D3fOUnm4a@GjhpnWOqe6D21@uKvbQenk9EdNa5QeNcxRAGJ9fSAR5/OoYa4OVCQmBsQAys99uKsv8v///5YA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua (LuaJIT)](https://luajit.org/), 122 bytes

```lua
r=n.rep;for i=1,n*2 do print(i<=n+0 and r(' ',n-i)..r("/",i*2-2)..r('^L',n)or r(' ',i-1-n)..r("\\\\",n*2-i)..r(' "',n))end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCsMgFET3OcXHjZr6bRW6ar1Bj1AKUiP8Er5BkvNb03RgFsO8mXmLOG/xQ2vLG79XKgxZsW41sK3TcsulAgVnePSQCiyVeFV0D3y6QOQEVUmQhpG0tVWJszA0evS/JF@PXun@cFCEDvngnl1iP/0PJYgd1ROn1j0gOu@HrKy1urXrFw)

(Above code abuses the TIO's input string-type to save 1 byte, see
[Not abused version](https://tio.run/##LYzBCsIwEETv/Yoll2xKNtKcBO0f@AkiVNvASt2UkHx/TK0DcxjmzaxlorVMb841FHlljgIBxdQ0otbGpWW7hJiAx8FK72GOsCWWjHwdBSaZIaEGbYXYOJdQnZTl3pP/Jf24tcq0/UExDSQHd29S@@V/qEHtqFlkrs0d0eB9FzBHKZ/nktA5Z0yt5y8))

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 68 bytes

```
~:i,.-1%]zip.-1%]{{~" "*\["//""\\\\"]0=*+["^L"' "']0=i*+}%1:0;n*}%n*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v84qU0dP11A1tiqzAExXV9cpKShpxUQr6esrKcUAgVKsga2WdrRSnI@SuoKSOpCXqaVdq2poZWCdp1Wrmqf1/78lAA)

Its really messy, but it works and I don't really know a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 114 bytes

```
=LET(x,A1,q,SEQUENCE(2*x),b,q>x,r,IF(b,q-x-1,x-q),REPT(" ",r)&REPT(IF(b,"\\","//"),x-r)&REPT(IF(b,"""""","^L"),x))
```

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnB_Q6r1yxIKXAP04?e=DC5Wq8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate), 84 bytes

```
(( {#2-1}| {$~1-1})(//$3|)(^L){$~1}\n){$~1}(( $6|)(\\{#7-2}|\\{#3})( "){$~1}\n){$~1}
```

Takes the size as a command-line input. [Try it here!](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/regenerate)

#### Explanation

Spaces are replaced with underscores for improved visibility.

Top half:

```
(( {#2-1}| {$~1-1})(//$3|)(^L){$~1}\n){$~1}
(                                    )       Group 1: one row of the top half
 (                )                           Group 2: leading spaces
  _{#2-1}                                      Either one less space than the previous row
         |_{$~1-1}                             or (input-1) spaces if this is the first row
                   (     )                    Group 3: slashes
                    //$3                       Either the previous row's slashes plus two more
                        |                      or empty string if this is the first row
                          (^L)                Group 4: ^L
                              {$~1}           Repeat group 4 (input) times
                                   \n         Newline
                                      {$~1}  Repeat group 1 (input) times
```

Bottom half:

```
(( $6|)(\\{#7-2}|\\{#3})( "){$~1}\n){$~1}
(                                  )       Group 5: one row of the bottom half
 (    )                                     Group 6: leading spaces
  _$6                                        Either the previous row's spaces plus two more
     |                                       or empty string if this is the first row
       (               )                    Group 7: backslashes
        \\{#7-2}                             Either two fewer slashes than the previous row
                |\\{#3}                      or the same number of slashes as in the last match
                                              of group 3 if this is the first row
                        (_")                Group 8: space-quote
                            {$~1}           Repeat group 8 (input) times
                                 \n         Newline
                                    {$~1}  Repeat group 5 (input) times
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-M5.10.0 -pa`, 71 bytes

```perl
say,$\=y'/^L'\ "'r.$/.$\for map$"x("@F"-$_--)."//"x$_."^L"x"@F",1..$_}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJHJca2Ul0/zkc9RkFJvUhPRV9PJSYtv0ghN7FARalCQ8nBTUlXJV5XV1NPSV9fqUIlXk8pzkepAiSuY6inpxJfW/3/v@W//IKSzPy84v@6BYn/dX1N9QwN9AwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), <sup><s>79</s> <s>73</s></sup> 69 bytes

output is a list of lines

```
f(N,a=-N+1:0,b=0:N-1)=@.[" "^-a*"//"^b*"^L"^N;" "^b*"\\"^-2a*" \""^N]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P03DTyfRVtdP29DKQCfJ1sDKT9dQ09ZBL1pJQSlON1FLSV9fKS5JSynORynOzxokCOTExADljICSCjFKQOHY/wVFmXklOXl6GmkappqaXEhcQ0NUvhGCC@H9BwA)

Comment: If you can print one space less on the left. But anyway yes, you did it

Comment: I can but it will cost me a few bytes

Comment: Don't worry about a few bytes, the important thing is that you managed to properly reproduce the shape in as few bytes as your language allow you to do.

Comment: @Davide done, and I even managed to shave a few more bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 26 bytes

```
ʁd\/*m‛^L‛ ""?*ƛw?ẋ;fZvṅøĊ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%CA%81d%5C%2F*m%E2%80%9B%5EL%E2%80%9B%20%22%22%3F*%C6%9Bw%3F%E1%BA%8B%3BfZv%E1%B9%85%C3%B8%C4%8A&inputs=10&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 31 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Æç'Li^)i'/pXÑÃû
c¡Xd`/\\^ L"`Ãw
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=xucnTGleKWknL3BY0cP7CmOhWGRgL1xcXiBMImDDdw&input=NQ)

```
Æç'Li^)i'/pXÑÃû\nc¡Xd`...`Ãw     :Implicit input of integer U
Æ                                :Map each X in the range [0,U)
 ç                               :  U times repeat
  'Li^                           :    "L" prepended with "^"
      )                          :  End repeat
       i                         :  Prepend
        '/p                      :    "/" repeated
           XÑ                    :    X*2 times
             Ã                   :End map
              û                  :centre pad each element with spaces to the length of the longest
               \n                :Reassign to U
                 c               :Concatenate
                  ¡              :  Map each X in U
                   Xd`...`       :    For each pair of characters in the string, replace all occurrences of the first in X with the second
                          Ã      :  End map
                           w     :  Reverse
                                 :Implicit output joined with newlines
```